# How do I tell if an individual file is compressed in BTRFS?

Tags: compression, btrfs

I believe I have correctly compressed some files, but not others. How do I verify this?

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question but it has gone unanswered. There is now a tool called [**compsize**](https://github.com/kilobyte/compsize) which handles exactly what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Fedora has compsize packaged](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/compsize), also [SuSE has it](https://software.opensuse.org/package/compsize).

```
$ sudo dnf install compsize
$ rm -f testfile;sync;head -qc10m /dev/zero >testfile;sync;compsize testfile
Type       Perc     Disk Usage   Uncompressed Referenced  
TOTAL        3%      320K          10M          10M       
zlib         3%      320K          10M          10M
```

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible, because this information is not stored: each file must be checked individually by a tool that do not exist yet.

See [How do I find out the compressed / uncompressed file sizes on btrfs?](https://superuser.com/questions/670125/how-do-i-find-out-the-compressed-uncompressed-file-sizes-on-btrfs) for more details ans links.

Answer (score 0):

The [`btrfs` wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_find_out_compression_ratio_of_a_file.3F) indicates that there is a patch which may do what you're after:

> There's a patchset
>   http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.btrfs/37312 that
>   extends the FIEMAP interface to return the physical length of an
>   extent (ie. the compressed size). The size obtained is not exact and
>   is rounded up to block size (4KB). The real amount of compressed bytes
>   is not reported and recorded by the filesystem (only the block count)
>   in it's structures. It is saved in the disk blocks but solely
>   processed by the compression code.

You could compare the length of the extent to the size of the file. Compression status of sparse files may be trickier to determine.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I was looking for a way to see if a file has a compression flag attached to it.

I believe this is also the original question, so this is the answer I finally figured out.

```
btrfs property get yourfile.txt
```

Seems like there is also parameter -t for specifying the  but at least on Synology, it doesn't accept compression type.